# How to export Blender 2.8 for Elements 3D/After Effects (+ Node material)?

Tags: materials, export

I'm new to Blender, but thanks to a few tutorials online, managed to create a cool fireball effect I'd like to utilize in one of my upcoming videos (hence Elements 3D / After Effects).

But, despite exporting the object and loading the mtl files into Elements 3D, all I get is the following:

[image: Elements 3D/After Effects]

The animation works great, and I'm getting the opacity, but that's about it.

To help clarify, below are some screenshots of what I'm trying to produce... but everything about the material was created using a node tree, which might be the issue?

Desire Result:
[image: Desired Result]

Full Node Tree:
[image: Full Node Tree]

Zoom in:
[image: Zoom in]

Just to show material location (within isosphere)
[image: Material]

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I tried learning how to bake this using a YouTube tutorial, but I think because I'm not using Principled BSDF, it's not working? I'm honestly unsure. Sorry for such a newbie question!

Answer (score 0):

I don't now about Elements 3D / After Effects material system, but I'm sure there is no direct solution for node setup export.

Nonetheless typical workflow is to bake material textures in Blender and apply them in other editor.
I prefer [Principled-Baker](https://github.com/danielenger/Principled-Baker) addon.